# Which components are using virtual addresses, linear addresses, physical addresses and logical addresses?

Tags: data

I'm a bit confused about the different types of addresses in an operating system:

- **virtual addresses**
  are entirely used from the CPU ?
- **physical addresses**
  are used from what kind of hardware?
- **linear addresses**
  are used from ?
- **logical addresses**
  are used from ?

You'd do me a big favor, if you upload a picture in order to see the areas of application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't draw a picture, that is your task, but I'll try to explain the basic relations of the concepts you mention.

The data residing in the *physical* memory chips is referred to using the **physical address space**. Only the most low-level parts of the operating system uses that.

**Logical address space** (*logical* here being used as a counterpart to *physical*) is what e.g. an application is using to refer to its data. In a very simple implementation it could be ***linear***, but since that approach has many drawbacks (one of them being the fact that large memory would require very long addresses), a *segmented* (the address being the pair (segment, offset)) or *paged* (which has the same idea but pages are always of identical size) approach has been usually taken.

**Virtual address space** refers to the fact that the addresses being used are *virtual* and do usually not correspond to the actual physical address space (which could be made of several non-contiguous blocks due to having many different memory devices, like RAM and a portion of a hard disk). In modern computers it also veils the address spaces of individual applications from each other so they couldn't interfere each other.

The above is a synthesis from the following sources:

[Computer Fundamentals: Architecture and Organization](https://books.google.fi/books?id=PVz_IvZr5lcC&lpg=SA5-PA49&ots=Tv2OguJ51i&dq=computer%20memory%20addresses%20virtual%20physical%20logical%20linear&pg=SA5-PA49#v=onepage&q=computer%20memory%20addresses%20virtual%20physical%20logical%20linear&f=false)

[Concise Encyclopedia of Computer Science](https://books.google.fi/books?id=5Jaa1BVverIC&lpg=PA145&ots=OxoQGzK-OE&dq=computer%20memory%20addresses%20virtual%20physical%20logical%20linear&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q=computer%20memory%20addresses%20virtual%20physical%20logical%20linear&f=false)

[Difference between physical/logical/virtual memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15851225/2745865)